# QGIS - How to request multiple layers in one WMS request?

Tags: qgis, wms, layers

How can I prompt QGIS to do a single WMS request of two layers instead of doing two seperate requests?

What I try to achieve per view:

```
https://myservice.org/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&...&LAYERS=a,b
```

What QGIS is doing right now per view:

```
https://myservice.org/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&...&LAYERS=a
https://myservice.org/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&...&LAYERS=b
```

The question is related to my other one here: [WMS cross-layer rendering question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458081/wms-cross-layer-rendering-question).

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. User can select several layers from the WMS connection and keep the "Load as separate layers" unchecked and that makes me think that QGIS should then request a list of layers. However, it does not but it includes only one layer. I would write mail into qgis users mailing list and ask if there is a bug.

Comment: Thank you. Currently, I'm unable to find a "Load as separate layers" option (QGIS 3.30). Do you mean Browser > WMS/WMTS > Right-Click on the Connection > Edit connection? There I cannot find such an option...

Comment: It is not defined in the connection but later, when you select the layers from the service https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Y8k.png.

Comment: It is worth noting perhaps that if you request two layers `LAYERS=a,b&` in a GetMap request the service will provide one image with layer b drawn on top of layer a, which may not be the effect you want.

Comment: @user30184: Ok, I found the option under Menu > Layer > Data Source Manager > WMS/WMTS, and the option is indeed unchecked. Strange. Now, meanwhile I found another possibility: Menu > Layer > Add Layer > Add WMS/WMTS Layer > add layer a and b from the list and Close the dialog via Add. Then I get one new layer in the Layer list on the left that "owns" layers a and b, resulting in LAYERS=a,b in the GetMap request. That's exactly the thing I was looking for. Thank you anyway :-)

Comment: @nmtoken: Thanks for the comment. I think it depends on how the WMS does render the resulting image: If the WMS supports something like cross-layer rendering then the result might look much better than just stacking the layers (please look at the discussion here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458081/wms-cross-layer-rendering-question). If there is no such support, in my opinion the visual result of a &LAYERS=a,b request would be the same as the LAYERS=a request overlaid by LAYERS=b request.

Comment: Not exactly, `LAYERS=a,b` might result different than `LAYERS=a` overlaid with `LAYERS=b` because of labels. Labels are always on top whatever the geometry and the layer order in the legend in QGIS desktop.

Comment: Can you add two layers from this service https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wms?VERSION=1.3.0? I couldn't. The layer name shows World country boundaries/World continents but GetMap has only "country_bounds" in &layers=

Comment: @etrimaille: That's what I meant with cross-layer rendering: If the WMS aims to draw non-overlapping labels for layers a and b (after drawing the other content of a and b), it needs a "LAYERS=a,b" request and some labeling logic that takes both layers into account. But if the WMS simply stacks layer a (with labels) and layer b (with labels) then the result would be equal to the "LAYERS=a" response overlaid by the "LAYERS=b" response. Or do you have a different setting in mind where labels are requested separately using additional requests?

Comment: @user30184: Yes, seems to work: The resulting URL (Layer list > the new layer > Properties > Information) shows ...&layers=continents&layers=country_bounds&layers=cities which is, as far as i know, just another valid spelling of ...&layers=continents,country_bounds,cities.

Comment: Section 7.3.3.3 LAYERS  of the WMS 1.3.0 specification says : `A WMS shall render the requested layers by drawing the leftmost in the list bottommost, the next one over that, and so on`

Comment: @nmtoken: Clear, but the result depends on how "relaxed" your interpretation of the spec is due to practical terms - e. g. are labels set globally and always "on top" and so on. See the discussion in the SO link I mentioned above.

Comment: Repeated &layers is wrong by the WMS standard. This WMS server seems to take the last &layers from the wrong request. Compare https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-90%2C-180%2C83.627419%2C180&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=1069&HEIGHT=515&LAYERS=continents,country_bounds&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
and https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-90%2C-180%2C83.627419%2C180&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=1069&HEIGHT=515&LAYERS=continents&layers=country_bounds&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

Comment: The WMS standard tells us that `When request parameters are duplicated with conflicting values, the response from the server may be undefined.  This International Standard does not mandate which of the duplicated values sent by the client are to be used by the server`

Comment: So, to resolve that &layers=a&layers=b (wrong syntax) vs. &layers=a,b (corrent) issue you may file a bug to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues ? I didn't find related issues there...

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in the way QGIS desktop constructs WMS GetMap requests then file a bug report.  If you would like QGIS desktop to allow better control of layers requested in a GetMap request, file an enhancement request.  There doesn't have to be any similar issues/requests for you to do this.